# Closed form expression for $\psi_{e^{\pi}}^{(3)}(1-i)$

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, mathematica, digamma-function, polygamma

Let $\psi_q(z)$ be the q-DiGamma function defined for a real variable $\Re(z)>0$ as $$\psi_q(z)=\frac{1}{\Gamma_q(z)}\frac{\partial}{\partial z} (\Gamma_q(z))$$
where $\Gamma_q(z)$ is the q-Gamma function defined as $$\Gamma_q(z)=(1-q)^{1-z}\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1-q^{n+1}}{1-q^{n+z}}$$

**Question** I am looking for a closed form for $$\psi_{e^{\pi}}^{(3)}(1-i)$$ where $i=\sqrt{-1}$

Here is a beautiful answer for calculating $$\psi_{e^{\pi}}^{(3)}(1)$$

Wolfram Alpha [gives](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=qpolygamma%283%2C1%2Cx%29) the expansion at $x=\infty$:

$$\psi_x^{(3)}(1)=\ln^4(x)\left(x^{-1}+9x^{-2}+\dots\right)$$

and these match Oeis [A$001158$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=qpolygamma%283%2C1%2Cx%29) with [divisor $\sigma_v(n)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=divisorsigma%283%2Cn%29) and various theta functions after plugging the sum back in [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=ln%28x%29%5E4+sum%5Bdivisorsigma%283%2Cn%29%2Fx%5En%2C%7Bn%2C1%2Cinfty%7D%5D). Use $\vartheta_v(0,x)=\vartheta_v(x)$:

$$\psi_x^{(3)}(1)=\ln^4(x)\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sigma_3(n)}{x^n}=\frac{\ln^4(x)}{480}\left(\vartheta_2\left(\frac1{\sqrt x}\right)^8+ \vartheta_3\left(\frac1{\sqrt x}\right)^8+ \vartheta_4\left(\frac1{\sqrt x}\right)^8-2\right)$$

Therefore:

$$\psi_{e^\pi}^{(3)}(1)=\frac{\pi^4}{480}\left(\vartheta_2^8\left(e^{-\frac\pi2}\right)+ \vartheta_3^8\left(e^{-\frac\pi2}\right)+ \vartheta_4^8\left(e^{-\frac\pi2}\right)-2\right)$$

Clicking “more digits” [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=qpolygamma%283%2C1%2Ce%5Epi%29-lim%5Bsum%5Bln%28x%29%5E4+sigma%283%2Cn%29%2Fx%5En%2C%7Bn%2C1%2Cinfty%7D%5D%2Cx-%3Eexp%28pi%29%5D) shows a smaller error each time implying the result is true.

Now use Dedekind $\eta(z)$ identities for $\vartheta_v\left(e^{-\frac\pi2}\right)$ when [$v=2$](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/EllipticTheta2/03/01/02/0001), [$v=3$](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/EllipticTheta3/03/01/02/0001/), and [$v=4$](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/EllipticTheta4/03/01/02/0001/)

$$\psi_{e^\pi}^{(3)}(1)= \frac{\pi^4}{480}\left(\left(2\frac{\eta^2(i)}{\eta\left(\frac i2\right)}\right)^8+\left(\frac{\eta^5\left(\frac i2\right)}{\eta^2\left(i\right)\eta^2\left(\frac i4\right)}\right)^8+\left(\frac{\eta^2\left(\frac i4\right)}{\eta\left(\frac i2\right)}\right)^8-2\right)$$

Using [special values](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_eta_function) in terms of $\Gamma\left(\frac14\right)$:

$\eta\left(\frac i4\right)=2\eta(4i)=\frac{\sqrt[4]{\sqrt2-1} \Gamma\left(\frac14\right)}{2^\frac{13}{16}\pi^\frac34},\eta\left(\frac i2\right)=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac14\right)}{2^\frac 78\pi^\frac34},\eta(i)=\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac14\right)}{2\pi^\frac34}$

Finally, [substitute](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=pi%5E4%2F480+%28%282+a%5E2%2Fb%29%5E8%2B%28b%5E5%2F%28a%5E2+c%5E2%29%29%5E8%2B%28c%5E2%2Fb%29%5E8-2%29%2Cc%3D%28%E2%88%9A2-1%29%5E%281%2F4%29+gamma%281%2F4%29%2F%282%5E%2813%2F16%29+pi%5E%283%2F4%29%29%2Cb%3Dgamma%281%2F4%29%2F%282%5E%287%2F8%29+pi%5E%283%2F4%29%29%2Ca%3Dgamma%281%2F4%29%2F%282+pi%5E%283%2F4%29%29) and have a form in terms of $\Gamma\left(\frac14\right)$ which has [no elementary closed form](https://oeis.org/A068466). Therefore:

$$\boxed{\psi_{e^\pi}^{(3)}(1)=\frac{11\Gamma\left(\frac14\right)^8}{5120\pi^2}-\frac{\pi^4}{240}}$$

[**shown here**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=qpolygamma%283%2C1%2Ce%5Epi%29-%28-64+%CF%80%5E6+%2B+33+%CE%93%281%2F4%29%5E8%29%2F%2815360+%CF%80%5E2%29)

If anyone could please solve this question by hand or mathematica or sage math. I would be highly indebted to you all.

Comment: Why do you expect that there is a closed form?

Comment: @Gary Thanks for your comment. I believe that there is a closed form because it is very close to the value which has been proved in the question.

Comment: Well if $1$ is close to $1-\mathrm{i}$, then so is $1/4$ to $1/2$. But unlike $\Gamma(1/2)$, $\Gamma(1/4)$ does not have a simple closed form.

Comment: @Gary I am sorry. Actually by close I meant that can we do this question in a similar way to that given in the post?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what methods did your professor use to solve similar questions?

Comment: @TymaGaidash He has left this for me to think. Seeing your response to my previous question, I think you can solve it. So please give it a try.

Comment: Your constant has this [series](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum%5B-π%5E4%2F%28e%5E%28π+n+%2B+π%29+%2B+1%29+%2B+%287+π%5E4%29%2F%28e%5E%28π+n+%2B+π%29+%2B+1%29%5E2+-+%2812+π%5E4%29%2F%28e%5E%28π+n+%2B+π%29+%2B+1%29%5E3+%2B+%286+π%5E4%29%2F%28e%5E%28π+n+%2B+π%29+%2B+1%29%5E4%2C%7Bn%2C0%2Cinfty%7D%5D).

Comment: @TymaGaidash Thanks a lot. I would appreciate if we can have a closed form for the series. Please write an answer if possible. I will with utmost respect accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not an expert in such sums, this derivation can probably be done in a simpler way. From the link provided by Tyma Gaidash, we have
\begin{align*}
\psi _{{\rm e}^\pi  }^{(3)} (1 - {\rm i}) = & - \pi ^4 \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{{\rm e}^{\pi n}  + 1}}}  + 7\pi ^4 \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{({\rm e}^{\pi n}  + 1)^2 }}} \\ & - 12\pi ^4 \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{({\rm e}^{\pi n}  + 1)^3 }}}  + 6\pi ^4 \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{({\rm e}^{\pi n}  + 1)^4 }}} .
\end{align*}
Re-expanding the fractions in powers of ${\rm e}^{-\pi n}$, changing the order of summation and re-summing again leads to the identities
\begin{align*}
& \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{{\rm e}^{\pi n}  + 1}}}  = -\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^k }}{{{\rm e}^{\pi k}  - 1}}} ,
\\ &\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{({\rm e}^{\pi n}  + 1)^2 }}}  = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^k k}}{{{\rm e}^{\pi k}  - 1}}}  - \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^k }}{{{\rm e}^{\pi k}  - 1}}} ,
\\ & \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{({\rm e}^{\pi n}  + 1)^3 }}}  = -\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^k k^2 }}{{{\rm e}^{\pi k}  - 1}}}  + \frac{3}{2}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^k k}}{{{\rm e}^{\pi k}  - 1}}}  - \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^k }}{{{\rm e}^{\pi k}  - 1}}} ,
\\ &\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{({\rm e}^{\pi n}  + 1)^4 }}}  = \frac{1}{6}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^k k^3 }}{{{\rm e}^{\pi k}  - 1}}}  - \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^k k^2 }}{{{\rm e}^{\pi k}  - 1}}}  + \frac{{11}}{6}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^k k}}{{{\rm e}^{\pi k}  - 1}}}  - \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^k }}{{{\rm e}^{\pi k}  - 1}}} .
\end{align*}
Substituting back to the original formula yields the simpler form
$$
\psi _{{\rm e}^\pi  }^{(3)} (1 - {\rm i}) = \pi ^4 \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^k k^3 }}{{{\rm e}^{\pi k}  - 1}}} .
$$
Now [we have](https://oeis.org/A138503)
$$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^k k^3 q^k }}{{1 - q^k }}}  = \frac{{\theta _4^8 (0,q) - 1}}{{16}}
$$
for $|q|<1$ with $\theta_4$ being one of the [theta functions](http://dlmf.nist.gov/20.2.i). Hence,
$$
\psi _{{\rm e}^\pi  }^{(3)} (1 - {\rm i}) = \pi ^4 \frac{{\theta _4^8 (0,{\rm e}^{ - \pi } ) - 1}}{{16}}.
$$
Using the specific value
$$
\theta _4 (0,{\rm e}^{ - \pi } ) = \frac{{\pi ^{1/4} }}{{2^{1/4} \Gamma (3/4)}},
$$
(see equation $(45)$ [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html)) we finally have
$$\boxed{
\psi _{{\rm e}^\pi  }^{(3)} (1 - {\rm i}) = \frac{{\pi ^6 }}{{64\Gamma ^8 (3/4)}} - \frac{{\pi ^4 }}{{16}}.}
$$
[Numerical check](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=N%5BQPolyGamma%283%2C+1+-+i%2C+e%5Epi%29-pi%5E6%2F%2864*Gamma%283%2F4%29%5E8%29%2Bpi%5E4%2F16%2C15%5D).

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I really appreciate it. +1 for it. One question I have: How to simplify the following $$ \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{{\rm e}^{\pi n}  + 1}}}  = -\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^k }}{{{\rm e}^{\pi k}  - 1}}}$$

Comment: You mean how to derive this equality? It is told in my answer.

Comment: Yes you are right. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, but sorry I could not follow. Please add a line or two to explain that equality.

Comment: Use $$
\frac{1}{{{\rm e}^{\pi n}  + 1}} = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {( - 1)^{k + 1} {\rm e}^{ - \pi kn} } 
$$ and interchange the summations. Similarly for the other equalities.

Comment: Thanks. But then how can we interchange the summations. That is not always allowed according to my knowledge. We need some conditions right? Are those conditions satisfied?

Comment: Of course they are. You can check it yourself. Do some work!

Comment: Okay. Thank you

Comment: I tried some work but could not get it. Please tell me how the conditions for interchanging summations are satisfied here. I am satisfied with your answer and will surely accept it.

Comment: Since $$
\sum\limits_{n,k = 1}^\infty  {\left| {( - 1)^{k + 1} {\rm e}^{ - \pi kn} } \right|}  = \sum\limits_{n,k = 1}^\infty  {{\rm e}^{ - \pi kn} }  = \sum\limits_{j = 1}^\infty  {d(j){\rm e}^{ - \pi j} }  <  + \infty ,
$$ it follows from the Fubini–Tonelli theorem.

Comment: One last question: Please give a closed form for $\theta _4 (0,{\rm e}^{ - \pi x} )$ where $x>0$

Comment: There is not closed form in general. See however [this](http://dlmf.nist.gov/20.4.E5). I wonder why you need all this. I can sense from your comments that you are desperate to have a fully rigorous answer (without you doing any of the work).

Comment: Accepted the answer. Thanks